# Not able to send status to client using ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

//app.js
This is my register route, username is primary in loginDetails table in the table. So I am able to see that username is not being duplicated but not able to send that error message to registration_script.js. It is giving me failure callback all the time.

the following is the register route in server.js:

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {

    let dbConnectionObject = db.dbConnection();
    let status = 200;
    let status_msg = "New user has registered";
    let sql = "insert into loginDetails values('" + req.body.username + "','" + req.body.password + "')"

    dbConnectionObject.query(sql, function (err, result) {

        dbConnectionObject.end();
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            status = 404;
            status_msg = "Username exists";
            console.log("in if")
            return res.status(200).send(status_msg)
        }
        else {
            console.log("in app.js insert")
            console.log(result);
            return res.status(200).send(status_msg)

        }
    })
```

In the ajax call request, all the time failure callback is being triggered irrespective of if-else statement in app.js
//registration_script.js

```
 if ((password == $('#cpassword').val()) && ($('#password').val()) && ($('#user').val()) && ($('#cpassword').val())) {
            let login_new = {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: server_url + "/register",
                type: "post",
                data: login_new,
                //Success callback
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                    window.location.href = "../index.html";
                 }
                ,
                error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {

                    //error callback 
                    alert("Registration failed" + err + "stau" + status);

                }
            })
        }
```

so please help me in achieving success and failure callback with respective to the conditions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried debugging this and checking what the `err` parameter is?

Comment: You are returning a 200 status each time. It looks like you meant to type `return res.status(status).send(status_msg)` but you have `return res.status(200).send(status_msg)` in both parts of the `if...else` statement

Comment: So what is being returned from the server? Look at the call in the network panel.

Comment: It is returning 304 status code instead of 200

Comment: not sure how a post request would give a 304. So you are certain that the code above actually gets called.

Comment: What are you using to test this? cause if it's chrome then there's a chance the request is cached and it returns 304 in that situation

Comment: Yes I am using chrome, how to uncache it

Answer (score -1):

You should not return back a response with status 200 in your error block this part:

```
 if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        status = 404;
        status_msg = "Username exists";
        console.log("in if")
        return res.status(200).send(status_msg)
    }
```

instead do this

```
 return res.status(status).send(status_msg)
```